# Using an overlay to cover the body AND the input fields

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a website with a slide on div that fires when the user leaves the desired area.  I made a jsfiddle to somewhat show.

http://jsfiddle.net/qxcd8y1L/

```
 <body class="overlay">
  <input>
 </body>    

 .overlay{
    position: absolute;
    opacity: ;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #373737;
 }
```

Currently I know that I can change the opacity and the input will be darkened but I don't want that.  As my current app shows the div as it should be and it overlays the  as it should . BUT the problem is the input fields are still seen.

I know that you could make it where window events aren't active.  So someone couldn't click inside the input but that doesn't help as they need to be able to click the close button on the div that pops out.

I'm wanting a way to be able and attach the overlay to the body while also having it hide all the input fields underneath.  I tried searching quite a bit but nothing has been precisely that.

I'm working with jquery and css only . So please try and have something within those workings.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Solution: 1

You can use `:after` like this

```css
body:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #373737;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" />
</body>
```

> Solution: 2

You can use another `div` named `.overlay` like this. you can `show` or `hide` the `div` using `jQuery` as per your requirement

```css
.overlay{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #373737;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <input type="text" />
</body>
```

Comment: the first one is working on the jsfiddle but not on my app.  I'm looking into that now. but the second isn't showing up as yours does. trying to check that as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/qxcd8y1L/39/

Comment: tried to solve your problem as per your provided code @daneiswork

Comment: I'm trying to see how to add more of my code to the jsfiddle without getting crazy since it's a lot of code.  I appreciate it and going to keep going over it to see if I can tweak it per your help.

Comment: ** Edit.  Got it to work by setting the div i wanted to slide on with a z index :D **  ----- okay so the first solution works.  I have to figure out how to get my div that fires to be on top of the overlay now.  But the input is covered with that first solution you gave.  Thanks! Selecting your answer as its made the input become darkened as I was hoping for!

Answer (score 0):

Take a little look at my changes, it now works find.

Hope this helped you.

http://jsfiddle.net/qxcd8y1L/30/

This is the HTML file, also containing some JS functions :

```
 <body>
  <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
   <button onclick="dismiss()" class="close-button">
    Close Overlay
    </button>
  </div>


   <div class="container">

     <input> 
   </div>
</body>    



<script>

    function dismiss(){
            $(".overlay").removeClass("on");
    }


    $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".overlay").addClass("on");
    });

</script>
```

And of course, I needed a little bit of css to do this:

```
.overlay{
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #373737;
  transition: 2s opacity;
  z-index:-1;
  display:flex;
}
.on{
  opacity: 1;
  z-index:2;
}

.close-button{
   align-self:center;
   justify-self:center;
   margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: I'm still having the problem on my app.  I'm going to see if there's something i'm missing.  Thanks for the post.  Going to see if one of them works into it and can cover it up.

Comment: got it to work @menhdi but it was with too much tweaking and that's why i went with the other solution. thanks!